# NSTableViewDelegate selection and events

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'd like to know your thoughts about this somewhat odd behaviour of events related to `NSTableView` and `NSTextField`. In my application I've got a button for adding new rows to my NSTableView (cell-based).

If I click the Add Button,
`-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification` is called and a new row is adde, then focused/selected after I manually call `[tableView editColumn:0 row:selectedRowIndex withEvent:nil select:YES]` in that method.

Start typing some text in that cell, will trigger the `-void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)obj` event, however if I click the 'Add Button' again, thus leaving the cell - the event which I expect to be triggered
`-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj` is in fact not so.

The behaviour is different if I wouldn't have started typing anything in the cell in the first place.

How come?

Answer (score 0):

If you select another cell or text field controlTextDidEndEditing will be called, but in your case, you need to force the text field to end editing programmatically. You can use:

```
[[textField window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

(i.e. in addButton method). It will end editing and remove focus from the text field.

Comment: I don't have access to the textfield in my addButton method. The only thing I have access to in my delegate methods is the NSTableView. Any ideas on how to get a particular textfield, and not the textfieldCell.

Comment: You do not need a textfield control as such, you can resign the responder even using the tableView instance like [[tableView window] makeFirstResponder:nil];